# Alarm function won't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a very simple alarm application created through jQuery and Javascript. Unfortunately, the alarm aspect of the program won't work. The relevant piece of code is here:

```
var today = new Date();
var h = today.getHours();
var m = today.getMinutes();
var s = today.getSeconds();

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    current_Time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    current_Time;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

function checkForAlarm() {
  console.log("h :: " + h);
   console.log("m :: " + m);
   console.log("s :: " + s);
    if (h == 17 && m == 52 && s == 16) {
        console.log("play")
        //var audio = new Audio('Prince.mp3');
        audio.play();
    }
    else {
        console.log("not");
    }
}

window.setInterval(function(){
  checkForAlarm()
}, 1000);
```

If I remove the m and s variables and the h variable equals h, it runs fine, but if I run the application before the requested time, the audio never runs. Can someone help me out with this. Here is the full CodePen for reference:

http://codepen.io/kwikimart/pen/grkYoX

Comment: Try giving `500` instead of `1000`,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this piece of code

```
  function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
       --> var h = today.getHours();
       --> var m = today.getMinutes();
       --> var s = today.getSeconds();
```

You are redeclaring the variables `h, m, s` which are local to the `startTime` function

But when you are comparing with the `h,m, s` variables defined in the global scope, the values for which are the referenced when the code runs for the first time.

Get rid of `var` for the variables defined inside `startTime` function.

Use `console.log` statements inside `checkforAlarm` method, and you see it is still reflecting the old timestamp.

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWdKBA)**